# My email compose task keeps crashing when selecting an email

Tags: windows-phone-8

i am having a kind of weird situation with using the windows phone 8+ email compose Task. Even though the email selection is shown, after selecting outlook for example it crashes and returns back to my app, without sending the mail.

```
  EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
    email.To = "";
    email.Subject = DateTime.Now + " log from" + username;
    try
    {
       txt1 = await HelperClasses.StorageInteraction.ReadFile(HelperClasses.LocalUser.path);
       txt2 = await HelperClasses.StorageInteraction.ReadFile(HelperClasses.LocalUser.path+"1");
       email.Body = txt1 + "\r" + txt2;                  
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("File not found");
    } 
    if (email.Body.Length > 28000)
    {
       email.Body = email.Body.Substring(email.Body.Length - 28000);
       Debug.WriteLine("Email body after trimming it : " + email.Body);
    } 

email.Show();
```

so the question is, am i causing the outlook crash with the email.Body i provide? or is it just a malfunction of the windows phone OS/email app?

ps: i've read from other people on stackoverflow that they can send email.Body sizes up to 63K. So am i causing this?

Comment: Have you checked if it crashes if you send a different (for example, shorter) content?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if HelperClasses.LocalUser.path+"1" is correct. Remember 1 will be added after the file extension. So in case your first text file(or any other file type) is log.txt then the second one would be log.txt1 which is invalid. As a result the email.Body will be invalid. And you are using email.Show() even when an error occurs(which is handled by your catch block). So the email crashes when it is loaded. If the problem is what I have described above then try the following code

```
String ext=".txt"; \\ replace it with your file's extension
String path2=HelperClasses.LocalUser.path.ToString().SubString(0,HelperClasses.LocalUser.path.ToString()-ext.length)+"1"+ext;
```

Comment: according to your example, there is definately one issue with the names but still. as long as the email.show is called and run properly why the selection of a mail keeps crashing from time to time?